# What's the ios app that gives you share options when you take a screenshot?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, screen-capture

I remember taking a screenshot on my iPhone and being given additional options to share that page from the app, i.e. the app knew that I took a screenshot and proactively gave me the option of sharing that page. Do you guys know what app that might be?

Answer (score 1):

When you take a screenshot and the preview pops up in the bottom-left corner, just press and hold (for 1-2 seconds) on the preview. That will bring up the sharing panel right away.

---

Some additional details about screenshots if you're interested...

Any iOS app in the foreground can [detect a screenshot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18158483/190298) and react however it wants. I guess you were using some app that offered helpful sharing when you took a screenshot of that app specifically, but I have no idea what that might have been.

There are no apps** that can change the system-wide behaviour of screenshots to reveal the sharing options when you take a screenshot. iOS apps can't interfere with the system that way.

***Actually that's not totally true. If you're trying pre-release versions of apps through TestFlight, any screenshots taken in the pre-release app are [automatically converted](https://techcrunch.com/2019/06/03/apples-updated-testflight-will-let-users-submit-feedback-with-a-screenshot/) to suggested feedback for the developer.*